# Regex: How to get something between text, except something between other text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-negation

Ok, this is kind of trick. I have this text:

```
<something>
   <h1> quoiwuqoiuwoi aoiuoisquiooi

       <script> dsadsa  dsa </script>

       Some text here in the middle! =)   

       <script> dsadsa  dsa </script>

   </h1>
</something>
```

I want to get only the content in  without the  tags, in other words:

```
   <h1> quoiwuqoiuwoi aoiuoisquiooi


       Some text here in the middle! =)   


   </h1>
```

Including the  tags.

Doing some research I´ve found out I can get everything between the h1 tags with the following regex:

```
   /<h1([^]*)h1>/
```

How ever, I can´t find a way to exclude whats bettween the  tags. Including the script tag itself. Any help would be much apreciated.

In case anyone is wondering why I need that, here is a brief explanation:

I´m using this code to scrapy some data from a site using googleSpreadSheet:

```
function doGet() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.nespresso.com/br/pt/product/maquina-de-cafe-espresso-pixie-clips-c60-preta-e-lima-neon-110v').getContentText();
  var regExp = new RegExp("<h1([^]*)h1>", "gi");
  var h1 = regExp.exec(html);
  Logger.log(h1);
  var doc = XmlService.parse(h1[0]);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var menu = getElementsByClassName(html, 'nes_pdp-title nes_pdp-title-sep-none')[0];
  var output = menu.getText();
  Logger.log(output);
}
```

How ever it has a problem parssing script tags and iframes. the only solution I could find was to strip the code from them. If anyone has a better solution, I all ears.

If I don´t remove the script and iframe tags, the code breaks before I could call the .getElementsByTagName. It breaks when I use .XmlService(). I can only pass a valeu to XmlSevive() if it does not have a javascript nor a iframe tag.
Thank You again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `.innerHTML` of `h1` element using `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/<script>.*<\/script>/g` to match `script` tags including text within `script` tags , `.trim()`

```js
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("something")[0].querySelector("h1");
h1.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML.replace(/<script>.*<\/script>/g,"")
              .trim();
console.log(h1.outerHTML)
```

```html
<something>
   <h1> quoiwuqoiuwoi aoiuoisquiooi

       <script> dsadsa  dsa </script>

       Some text here in the middle! =)   

       <script> dsadsa  dsa </script>

   </h1>
</something>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code breaks due to the script tags before I could call the .getElementsByTagName. It breaks when I use .XmlService(). I can only pass a valeu to XmlSevive() if it does not have a javascript nor a iframe tag.

Comment: @user3347814 What is requirement ? If expected result is to include text returned from `.replace()` inside existing `h1` , e.g.; `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = res;`?